# Determining Cookies on Intranet/IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

I got some code to check if cookies are enabled and it works in IE and all browsers and when I deploy it to a website (I got the code from http://sveinbjorn.org/cookiecheck). However, when I deploy it to our intranet/proxy it doesn't work in IE (or locally as a file).

I think it's because (I read somewhere) it's thinking it's an intranet and therefore cookies are always enabled.

Is there a way to actually detect cookies on IE in this scenario as I need to know because I then go to another external facing site that relies on cookies being set to on and not blocked.

Here's the code:

```
function checkCookiesOLD() {
var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;
if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled) { 
  document.cookie="testcookie";
  cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
}
return (cookieEnabled);
}
```

I even tried this, but I think the bottom line is local/intranet means cookies on and reported on.

```
function checkCookies() {
    var cookieEnabled = navigator.cookieEnabled;
    if (cookieEnabled === false) return false;
    if (!document.cookie && (cookieEnabled == null || /*@cc_on!@*/false))
    {
        document.cookie = "testBTCookie=1";
        if (!document.cookie) return false;
        document.cookie = "testBTCookie=; expires=" + new Date(0).toUTCString();
    }

    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement something like storing the dummy cookie / reading the cookie and then determine if cookies are enabled based on that (add try / catch to prevent exceptions).

Comment: That doesn't work because on an intranet/local the 'block all cookies' is disabled and cookies are enabled. I need to check the actual real IE setting for 'internet' zone essentially. I really don't understand why IE has all these hard-coded rules things like whether cookies are enabled on an intranet.